# c# Covert.ToDecimal difference in the 3.5 and 4.5 framework and xp machine

Tags: c#, .net

I need help with this.
The following code runs fine on Win7/Win8 machine with both 3.5 and 4.5 .NET Framework installed.

```
CultureInfo info = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("hr-HR");
string ui = txtUkupanIznos.Text.Trim();
decimal pvalue;

if (decimal.TryParse(ui, NumberStyles.Any, info, out pvalue))
{
    decimal poreznaStopa = 0.00m;
    decimal ukupanIznos = 0.00m;
    try
    {
        poreznaStopa = Convert.ToDecimal(txtstopa.Text.Replace(".", ","), info);
        ukupanIznos = Convert.ToDecimal(ui.Replace(".", ","), info);
    }
    ...
```

But on XP machine with .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 installed, this throws a FormatException so I need to remove `Replace(".", ",")`

Why?

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that the regional settings defined for Croatia may have changed between these Windows versions. If you run the sample code in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to output the settings on the three different PCs, what do you see for number format?

Answer (score 0):

The culture wasn't defined pre Windows Vista more than likely. I'm guessing hr-HR may not have any meaning in the older OS's.